# Integrate mui-datatable with admin-on-rest

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, admin-on-rest

How to integrate mui-datatable with admin-on-rest?
Need the following options in the list view :

- move around ordering of columns
- show/hide columns
- change the number of rows for display
- print preview of table

Mui-datatable has these features. According to admin-on-rest documentation, we can use custom Datagrid. Can anyone explain how to do it?

Comment: Did you try instructions in docs - https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/List.html#using-a-custom-iterator ?

Answer (score 0):

Say you are making a custom-datagrid component 'MyIterator'. This component has to just make use two props that will 'auto-magically' be available to the child of 'List' component. One prop is `ids` and another is `data`.

The `ids` prop is an array of id of currently displayable data-items. And the `data` is an object containing the data for all the items displayable.

Something like this should do the part of making a custom-datagrid -

```
const MyIterator = ({ids, data}) => ids.map(id=><div key={id}><span>Label</span><span>{data[id].label}</span></div>)
```

Above example presumed the data-item object to have a property of 'label'.

And this is how a custom-datagrid can be made.